# FLEX: Push Notifications/Alerts when database updated

Tags: android, apache-flex, push-notification, remote-server

So i am trying to build a system based on apache flex which will be used in places offering services (bars, restaurants, etc) which will use smartphones to send an order to a server and the information will be received by an admin client on tablet or pc.

i am a bit stuck on how to make the admin client get notifications about new orders.

Would the best approach to be running a query every 10 seconds or so, or do you have any other ideas that could help out? thanx for your answers :)

Comment: Use a server side software that supports "push" notifications.  GraniteDS and/or LiveCycle can do this.  I'm not sure about BlazeDS.

Comment: currently my server side is build on php and apache. any chance i could use it with this?

Comment: I don't know; but this may get you started: https://www.google.com/search?q=PHP+Push+Notifications&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a